# Linkedin marketing API "No virtual resource found" RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND error when calling rest/adTargetingEntities endpoint

Tags: api, linkedin-api

#linkedin

We're trying to migrate our linkedin apis to the rest endpoints (due to sunset deadline)
As per the postman collection found [here](https://www.postman.com/linkedin-developer-apis/workspace/linkedin-marketing-solutions-versioned-apis/request/17563548-f3e6b1ba-53fa-4815-95c0-9a14d8e703c8), we call the rest/adTargetingEntities endpoint but receive a 404 error.

Our headers:

```
{
     'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`, 
     'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
     'Linkedin-Version': 202211
}
```

Full GET request:

https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adTargetingEntities?q=TYPEAHEAD&facet=List(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3AemployersAll)&query=Apple

Can someone please let us know why this isn't working? Is it a problem on our end or a bug on the LinkedIn API

Comment: We've tried with multiple adFacets and other combinations. Nothing works

Comment: Have you tried with a different value for the Linkedin-Version header ? That solved my issue with a different endpoint. According to the Postman collection that you reference, the value for the version should be 202304.